# Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file: * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a value of t

Tags: blockchain, config, solidity, web3js, hardhat

I get this error when i try to run my script on the rinkeby network:

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a value of type string.
```

```
     require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.1',
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY,
      accounts: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
    },
   
  },
};
```

.env File

```
process.env.STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY=https://eth-rinkeby.dotdotdot          
                                                                                 
process.env.PRIVATE_KEY=PRIVATE_KEY
```

Please what could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Because of the `dotenv` package, I'm assuming that you're using a `.env` file, not passing the environment variables though command-line params, docker, etc... Can you edit the question and share, with anonymized values, how exactly is your `.env` formatted? Including spaces, newlines, quotes, ... Also, is it in the same folder as the Hardhat config file?

Comment: You shouldn't have ```process.env``` prefixed in front of your environment variables.  They should just be like ```STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY``` instead.

Comment: I just added the .env file to the question. It's in the same folder with the hardhat config file.  The private key and Alchemy API key was added without a space, comma, and quotation marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a few things here but if you're using `create-react-app` your `.env` variables need to be prefixed with `REACT_APP`.  So by example your env variable `STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY` should be `REACT_APP_STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY`.  If you use `webpack` you might need to make some modifications in here as well.  Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked! I removed the prefix `process.env`  in front of the environment variable. Left with `STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY` and `PRIVATE_KEY` . Thank you!

Comment: @michyDavid glad to hear! Please make my answer the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

make sure both .env and hardhat.config.js are in the hardhat-tutorial folder

Answer (score 0):

check are you in root folder or not, if not then go to root of folder and try again

Answer (score 0):

Add goerli after networks and before url.

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    goerli:{
      url: process.env.STAGING_ALCHEMY_KEY,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
    }
  },
};
```