# * Invalid account: #0 for network: mumbai - Expected string, received undefined

Tags: ethereum, polygon, hardhat

When ever I run
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network mumbai

Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

- Invalid account: #0 for network: mumbai - Expected string, received undefined

I have no clue what to do to fix this I have been at this for like 4 days now.

Should I delete account 0 how do I even do that?

Here are 2 reference both dont work for me.
[Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file: * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a value of t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562457/error-hh8-theres-one-or-more-errors-in-your-config-file-invalid-value-undef)

[H88 Error: Invalid account: #0 for network: mumbai - Expected string, received undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543451/h88-error-invalid-account-0-for-network-mumbai-expected-string-received-u)

```
/* hardhat.config.js */
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");


module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337
    },

  mumbai: {
    url: "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com",
   accounts: [process.env.privateKey]
  }
  
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.4",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not loading the private key correctly from your .env file.

Do a:

```
npm install dotenv --save-dev
```

and add this at the top of your config:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env) // remove this after you've confirmed it working
```

The console log should now return your dotenv object

Comment: Thank you so much, though I reinstalled everything went well would have been nice to know if would have worked!